# Sql Stored procedure input parmeter contain apostrophe for a select

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure that takes input and gives a result, the stored procedure works fine.
the only time it fails is when input contains an apostrophe in input string.
every time i send an input lie this to procedure, in the database i do have some data that contains apostrophe.

here is the query

```
EXEC('Select C.Name, C.ID, C.Department'
+'From Customer C With (NO LOCK)'
+'Where(c.Name Like ''%' + @input+ ''%')'
);
```

Comment: Your SQL has potentially a lot more problems than just an extra apostrophe in the input.  You really need to learn about `parameterized queries` in order to better protect your database from badly (or maliciously) entered data.  Imagine if `@input` contained `Fred''%'); drop Customer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this and see if that helps.

```
EXEC('Select C.Name, C.ID, C.Department'
+'From Customer C With (NO LOCK)'
+'Where(c.Name Like ''%' + REPLACE ( @input , '''' , '''''' ) + ''%')'
);
```

My point is that you should escape the `'` by replacing it with `''`.